# Play Framework how to set jdbc properties after startup

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In my play application the database settings are not known before startup of the application. I have to read them from an environment variable after automatic deployment and start of the application.

The platform the app is deployed on is cloudfoundry. And there is a environment variable called VCAP_SERVICES (that is a json string). Here are all services listed e.g. the database service including the credentials

Is there a prefered way to do so? In means of still being able to use stuff like:

`DataSource ds = DB.getDatasource();`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use environment variables in your `application.conf`? See "Using environment variables" https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: I don't know it this is possible, since the format of the environment variable is a json string with several entries. The platform the app is deployed on is cloudfoundry. And there is a environment variable called VCAP_SERVICES. Here are all services listed e.g. the database service including the credentials

Comment: According to the docs, cloudfoundry should work out of the box. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Deploying-CloudFoundry

Comment: Cool, I did not know about this. I will try it... Still pretty new to Play!